# Adding www to domain in elasticbeanstalk ngnix

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS application running on ElasticBeanstalk. I want to redirect all request which are to basedomain.com to www.basedomain.com (Excluding SubDomain) and also add https.

I have updated .config file in .ebextension folder to redirect to https with following config file:

```
files:
  "/tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash

      CONFIGURED=`grep -c "return 301 https" /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`

      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i '/listen 8080;/a \    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }\n' /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules added"
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t nginx_rw "https rewrite rules already set"
          exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  00_appdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact
  01_configdeploy_rewrite_hook:
    command: cp -v /tmp/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact
  02_rewrite_hook_perms:
    command: chmod 755 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
  03_rewrite_hook_ownership:
    command: chown root:users /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/enact/45_nginx_https_rw.sh
```

Can someone help in adding www to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is better done with DNS redirection rather than nginx. Each DNS provider has a naked domain redirection solution you can use to move traffic from the naked domain to www.
For example, in Route 53 you do this with an Alias record. To do so open your Route 53 hosted zone for basedomain.com and create a new record set. Leave the name blank. Select A` type. Set alias to Yes and select basedomain.com from the S3 Website Endpoints section of the Alias Target dropdown. Your domain basedomain.com now redirects to www.basedomain.com

Comment: DNS Redirection is something not supported by Route53 so cant go for that solution

Comment: an A record would do the job you need. i've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate server whose job is to do redirects. and example nginx configuration to route `www.foo.com` to `foo.com`  would be:

`server {
        listen  80;
        server_name www.foo.com;
        return 301 $scheme://foo.com$request_uri;
    }`

Then in DNS you would point and A or CNAME `www.foo.com` to the server which runs nginx from above, and an A or CNAME record for `foo.com` to the beanstalk server.